# Getting PicklingError while converting rdd to spark dataframe

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My code is working fine if I dont write toDF , but when I try to convert an rdd to sparkdataframe getting the error. In my function I am fetching details from multiple dataframes and did a final join, from that finaljoinedDF dataframe , I used rdd.mappartitions to remove duplicates and get the final data. When I try to convert it into sparkdataframe by using toDF or createdataframe getting the below error. I am running the below code from aws glue job
I am very new to pyspark and python please help .

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

```
    newNameOfDatabase = (args["PROFILE_MASTER_RDS_TABLE_NAME"] + "_Temp" if args["ITERATION"] != "0" else args[
        "PROFILE_MASTER_RDS_TABLE_NAME"])
        
    s3BucketPath = generateBucketPath()
    # download the bank details in to s3 as we are unable to find connector to run procedure with spark
    pushBankDataToS3(s3BucketPath)
    logger.info("copied bank details to s3")
    userDF = user()
    logger.info("fetched user details")
    bankDF = getBankDetailsFromS3(s3BucketPath)
    logger.info("fetched bank details")
    segmentDF = segment()
    logger.info("fetched exchange details")
    poadpDF = poaDP()
    logger.info("fetched demat account details")
    tradeDF = iTradePrime()
    logger.info("fetched trade plan details")
    clientAddressDF = clientAddressDetails()
    logger.info("fetched client details")
    riskDF = risk()
    logger.info("fetched risk details")
    applicationDF = applicationNo()
    logger.info("fetched application number")
    depositoryDetailsDF = depositoryDetails()
    logger.info("fetched depository details")
    nomineeDetailsDF = nomineeDetails()
    logger.info("fetched nominee plan details")

    finalJoinedDF = userDF.join(bankDF, trim(upper(userDF["ClientId"])) == trim(upper(bankDF["PARTY_CODE"])), "left"). \
        join(poadpDF, trim(upper(userDF["ClientId"])) == trim(upper(poadpDF["PARTY_CODE"])), "left"). \
        join(segmentDF, trim(upper(userDF["ClientId"])) == trim(upper(segmentDF["Cl_code"])), "left"). \
        join(tradeDF, trim(upper(userDF["ClientId"])) == trim(upper(tradeDF["clientIdTrade"])), "left"). \
        join(clientAddressDF, trim(upper(userDF["ClientId"])) == trim(upper(clientAddressDF["cl_code"])), "left"). \
        join(riskDF, trim(upper(userDF["ClientId"])) == trim(upper(riskDF["cl_code"])), "left"). \
        join(applicationDF, trim(upper(userDF["ClientId"])) == trim(upper(applicationDF["PARTY_CODE"])), "left"). \
        join(depositoryDetailsDF, trim(upper(userDF["ClientId"])) == trim(upper(depositoryDetailsDF["cl_code"])),
             "left"). \
        join(nomineeDetailsDF, trim(upper(userDF["ClientId"])) == trim(upper(nomineeDetailsDF["NISE_PARTY_CODE"])),
             "left"). \
        orderBy("ClientId", "ACCNO")

    logger.info("Made final join")
    finalDF = finalJoinedDF.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda row: aggregateData(row)).toDF()
```

Comment: what does `aggregateData()` do? also, if you just want to remove duplicates, why not use `dropDuplicates()` or `distinct()`?

Comment: You should check what kind of objects the dataframes actually contain. It seems there is some object type included which cannot be serialized.

Comment: aggregateData() function removes duplicates and add only required column to final data in my example I am adding only one column `data.append(rows[0].ClientId.strip())`